# Input placeholders getting translated into spans on my page

Tags: html, css, input, placeholder

I have a page that is inheriting css from a masterpage, so I'm sure that something in that page is causing this weird issue, but I have not been able to figure out what it is. I have these input boxes on my page:

```
<div class="Filters" id="DateFilters">
    <input type="text" id="afterdate" placeholder="After Date" class="datebox" onchange="changeAfterDate(this)" value=""/>
    <input type="text" id="beforedate" placeholder="Before Date" class="datebox" onchange="changeBeforeDate(this)" value="" style="float: right" />
</div>
```

Before I attached the masterpage, it looked like this, which was how it was supposed to look

[image: 1]

However, after adding the masterpage, it looked like this:

[image: 2]

When I view the page source, the code is the same; however, when open Developer Tools in Chrome, the code looks like this:

```
<div class="Filters" id="DateFilters">
    <span class="input-placeholder-text" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute;">After Date</span>
    <input type="text" id="afterdate" class="datebox hasDatepicker" onchange="changeAfterDate(this)" value="">
    <span class="input-placeholder-text" style="color: rgb(0, 0, 0); position: absolute;">Before Date</span>
    <input type="text" id="beforedate" class="datebox hasDatepicker" onchange="changeBeforeDate(this)" value="" style="float: right">
</div>
```

Something is causing the placeholder text to be pulled out into its own span, and I have no idea why. Without the masterpage, the code looked exactly the way it did in my source when I inspected it.

Comment: Check to see if there is some placeholder plugin making this changes :)

Comment: How can I check that :] ?

Comment: See what scripts are loading on the page